# Can javascript detect when scrollbars are unavailable (i.e. on mobile browsers)?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I've got a javascript-based Scrolling Widget Thingy™. One of the things it does is create a fixed height `div` and gives it `overflow: auto`.

Alas on mobile Safari (and other mobile browsers) `overflow: auto;` doesn't show a scrollbar. Any content below "the fold" can only be found by accident.

Is there a way to detect this in javascript, *without* resorting to browser detection? e.g.

```
if (there is a scrollbar) {
    /* give me a fixed height and a scrollbar */
} else {
    /* Do something more suited to this situation */
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any easy solution. The *cleanest* solution would be to do browser detection to provide mobile vs standard versions of your page, rather than just one component, but this is not exactly easy (although there are tools to make this easier).

I did come across something while google searching, but not sure how much it helps you, if at all... 
http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: The reason I don't want to get into browser detection is maintenance. I want this to be a "fit and forget" solution, rather than something I need to update every time a new mobile device comes along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of resorting to dirty tricks:

1. Create 50x50 box
2. Set box to `overflow: auto`
3. Flood box with text
4. Read box inner size: if 50x50, something went wrong
5. Store result in variable and destroy box

... given that there's actually a way to measure the inner size, scrollbar excluded.

It's a scary algorithm anyway, hundreds of things can go wrong... Consider it just an idea.

Comment: As hacky as it might be, this might just work. clientWidth and clientHeight take scrollbars into account on the desktop. Now I need to do some testing on some mobile devices.

Comment: So, I created http://thinkdrastic.tumblr.com/post/870842095/ based on this idea. Seems to work. If anyone's got any feedback, please let me know! Thanks again Álvaro.

Comment: I've just spotted that Firefox 16 and newer have `element.scrollLeftMax` and `element.scrollTopMax` which could be helpful here. See http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/determining-when-an-element-is-scrollable-in-gecko/