# Detect if mobile browser supports overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

Is there a simple JavaScript solution for this that is device- and library agnostic?

I'd like to add a class to the html element so I can deliver scrollable containers to mobile when possible.

This would be a similar approach that Modernizr takes, detecting feature support instead of browser detection. I just don't want to use the whole Modernizr framework. Trying to keep the JavaScript light for a mobile project.

Thanks!

Comment: please put some effort on your question,

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343311/can-javascript-detect-when-scrollbars-are-unavailable-i-e-on-mobile-browsers. Also see: http://lostmonocle.com/post/870842095/geeky-stuff-using-jquery-to-check-if-scrollbars-are

Comment: I was thinking something more like this, but having trouble finding it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911866/how-to-detect-lack-of-positionfixed-in-a-generic-way

Comment: This is a valid question. The examples above check position: fixed and if scroll bars are visible. Neither example checked for overflow: scroll support.

Comment: Maybe this isn't any help to you, but once you detect that the browser doesn't support `overflow:scroll`, here is a library that I've used as a fallback: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4.

Answer (score 5):

Its not perfect but I am using this to detect -webkit-overflow-scrolling.

```
var overflowScrolling = typeof($("body")[0].style["-webkit-overflow-scrolling"]) !== "undefined";
```

Then I say if not `overflow-scrolling` and mobile then I load iScroll.

It means that devices that support `overflow: scroll` but not `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` will still load iScroll but this at least gives native scrolling to iOS 5 and modern android.

Comment: you probably want to replace the hyphen with an underscore?

Comment: This checks for support for `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`, not whether `overflow:scroll` works in the browser.

Comment: @speedarius that is what the first sentence states.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that checks for all possible options, including non-vendor prefixed properties and doesn't have any dependencies on libraries like jQuery or Modernizr:

```
function hasOverflowScrolling() {
    var prefixes = ['webkit', 'moz', 'o', 'ms'];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var hasIt = false;

    body.appendChild(div);

    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
        var prefix = prefixes[i];
        div.style[prefix + 'OverflowScrolling'] = 'touch';
    }

    // And the non-prefixed property
    div.style.overflowScrolling = 'touch';

    // Now check the properties
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(div);

    // First non-prefixed
    hasIt = !!computedStyle.overflowScrolling;

    // Now prefixed...
    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
        var prefix = prefixes[i];
        if (!!computedStyle[prefix + 'OverflowScrolling']) {
            hasIt = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Cleanup old div elements
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

    return hasIt;
}

alert(hasOverflowScrolling());
```

Comment: This checks for browser support for `-*-overflow-scrolling`, which controls "momentum" scrolling in mobile devices. It does not check whether `overflow:scroll` works in the browser. For example, in Android < 3.0, `overflow:scroll` simply does not work. I believe that is what the question is about.

Comment: This give me alway false everywhere

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question. Unfortunately, currently there seems to be no way to reliably check for `overflow: scroll` support.

Filament group has a polyfill for this which you may want to use in your projects (see http://filamentgroup.github.io/Overthrow/), but according to themselves:

> The trouble is, it's hard – perhaps impossible – to test for overflow
>   support [...]
>
> Out of necessity, Overthrow examines the user agent
>   string to whitelist the current and future versions of mobile
>   platforms that are known to have native overflow support, but not
>   before checking through more reliable and agnostic means: namely,
>   iOS5's (and now Chrome Android's too!) touch scrolling CSS property,
>   and a broad desktop browser inference test (no touch event support
>   with a screen greater than 1200px wide)